# DateTime Interface to be used for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime

Hi So I have created an interface for datetime like this:

```
public interface ITimeProvider<T>
{
    T Now { get; }
    string ToShortDateString();
}
```

And then I have one implamentation of that interface like this:

```
public class DateTimeProvider : ITimeProvider<DateTime>
{

    private DateTime _date;

    public DateTime Now
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }

    public  DateTimeProvider()
    {

        _date = new DateTime();
    }
    public string ToShortDateString()
    {
        return _date.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Then I am using it in my main unit and want to use property injection but i ran into some problems, here is a snap of what I have:

```
public class Atm : IAtm
{
   public ITimeProvider _timeProvider { get;set; }
}
```

This doesn't work as I don't specifiy a type. I could just do

```
public ITimeProvider<DateTime> _timeProvider { get;set; }
```

But then I wouldn't be able to use another timeprovider. I have also considered(and is the only solution I could come up with) is to make ATM generic so something like this

```
 public class Atm<T> : IAtm
 {
      public ITimeProvider<T> _timeProvider { get;set; }
 }
```

But then I feel like I can't use property injection, is there any other way I can do this so I will be able to test it?

Comment: "but I ran into some problems". "doesn't work as I don't specify a type", but you have registered your implementation of the interface with the injection container I assume?

Comment: *“But then I wouldn't be able to use another timeprovider”* – How likely is it that you are considering using a different type than `DateTime` to represent dates and times?

Comment: It isn't but I do want to mock it out for testing

Comment: You only need to be able to mock `DateTime.Now` for testing (which you are with that time provider). There is no reason to encapsulate the whole `DateTime` type; you can just create the datetime objects the way you need it for testing purposes.

Comment: @Sumsar1812 - Can you please explain why do you need `DateTime` to be a generic type parameter?

Comment: To me there is just an easier way.  Any class that relies on DateTime.Now checks.........just have an extra constructor property called "DateTime compareDate"..........then any non unit-test code will just pass in DateTime.Now...and a unittest can pass in a coded date.  I never randomly code "DateTime.Now" in my classes...it is always passed in from "above".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are abstracting is the `DateTime.Now` function not the `DateTime` datatype, you can keep the implementation the exactly the same but just fix the type.

```
public interface ITimeProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
    string ToShortDateString();
}

public class DateTimeProvider : ITimeProvider
{

    public DateTime Now
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }

    public string ToShortDateString()
    {
        return Now.ToShortDateString();
    }
}


public class RemoteTimeProvider : ITimeProvider
{
    public DateTime Now
    {
        get 
        { 
            using(var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var timeString = client.DownloadString(http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now);
                return DateTime.Parse(timeString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).ToLocalTime()
            }

        }
    }

    public  DateTimeProvider()
    {

    }
    public string ToShortDateString()
    {
        //ToDo
    }
}
```

Also, I don't really get what your `ToShortDateString()` does, it does not take in a parameter and it just uses the value returned from `new DateTime()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_2) to be able to unit test system or other assemblies *not* under your control.

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass1
{ 
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCurrentYear()
        {
            int fixedYear = 2000;

            // Shims can be used only in a ShimsContext:
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                // Arrange:
                // Shim DateTime.Now to return a fixed date:
                System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = 
                () =>
                { return new DateTime(fixedYear, 1, 1); };

                // Instantiate the component under test:
                var componentUnderTest = new MyComponent();

                // Act:
                int year = componentUnderTest.GetTheCurrentYear();

                // Assert: 
                // This will always be true if the component is working:
                Assert.AreEqual(fixedYear, year);
            }
        }
}
```